# NHibernate; Update Id-property of entities in detached collection, when saving to database

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, repository

I use session-per-call to **save a detached collection** with possible **adds/updates** (so includes some transient objects). But **how to update the Id's of new instances**(transient), which was 0, but now (after saving to database) should have a value?

I mean; Update those Id's of the passed collection, after the database is updated properly.

Would you do this in the repository? If so, how? ..and if not, how else?

What about considering it's **cascading child collections** that may also have new instances, then it gets a bit complex.  Would appreciate some thoughts/advice on this.

```
   class StoreRepository
   {
        public static void SaveOrUpdate(List<Store> stores)
        {
            using (ISession session = FNH_Manager.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var s in stores)
                    { 
                        session.Get(typeof(Store), s.Id);
                        session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(s);
                    } 

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Does your code not work? Or are you looking for a more optimal way of writing it?

Comment: Of the passed collection, some entities (parent and/or children) are new (Id=0). After the method, those Id's are still =0, in the business logic collection, but not in the database obviously. So I need to update the business collection (with those new Id's), ether in this method, or after. Hope that makes sense..?

Comment: you should be letting nhibernate handle all the id's (unless your strategy is assigned). the id's should be there and ready to use after you flush or commit the transaction.

Comment: Yes NH creates Ids. What you mean "should be there"? Should "stores" collection here be updated with the new Id's on transaction.Commit?  Cause they are not, they are still 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Id's of transient instances not being set, seems to be due to using **SaveOrUpdateCopy**. As I commented here. [NHibernate: How is identity Id updated when saving a transient instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896001/nhibernate-how-is-identity-id-updated-when-saving-a-transient-instance/4903820#4903820)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that persistent object was not changed you can re-attach it to new session with `Lock` method and make modifications. New objects which Id=0 just `SaveOrUpdate`.

```
class StoreRepository
{
    public static void SaveOrUpdate(List<Store> stores)
    {
        using (ISession session = FNH_Manager.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                if(s.Id == 0)
                { 
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(s);
                } 

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, problem is not to save it, but to update the business entities with the newly assigned Id properties (for those entities that were new/transient)

Comment: I think nHibernate automatically assign Ids to newly created object on Saving. But you must `Commit` transaction

Comment: But I do commit, in code above ?   And you say the entities passed into the SaveOrUpdate() method should then have been updated with the new Id's, on commit? (not only in the database?)   It doesn't look like that is happening, when I break/step the code.